# Way to perform a drag action with my leapmotion controller on D3js Force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leap-motion

I generated a D3js froce directed graph and I was looking for a way to perform a drag action with my leapmotion controller. I tried to simulate a mouseover event and parse the leapmotion closest finger x, y coordinate to the function below when a frame is detected:

```
function mouseSim(x, y) {
var ev = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');

ev.initMouseEvent(
    "mouseover",
    true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */,
    window, null,
    x, y, x, y, /* coordinates */
    false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
    0 /*left*/, null
);
document.dispatchEvent(ev);

}
```

But unfortunately I was unable to see any interaction.

I then though of a different approach. Create a custom event that will arise when the leapmotion closest finger is hovering a node(force directed node). Then call froce.drag().

The problem is I don't know how to create the custom event. If there is any easier way to do what I am trying to achieve I would appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: This sounds almost exactly what I've done [here](http://www.larsko.org/v/lff/). Source available [here](https://github.com/larskotthoff/leap-forceFingers).

Comment: I saw your Source code already and to be honest I wasn't really clear about it. Can you comment it so that I can understand? I am know to D3js and Javascript all together but I am a fast learner.

Comment: Are there any particular parts you're struggling with?

Comment: I wanted to know where exactly you define the drag behavior. Do you update the coordinate of the dragged element using the tick function?